# JAR compiled on 64 bit Windows wont run on 32 bit

Tags: java, windows, jar, 32bit-64bit

I have just developed and exported a Runnable JAR using Eclipse on my 64 Bit Windows 7 Laptop. I have just been trying it on other  computers and it works on another Windows 7 x64 laptop when you double click it. However, on a 32  Bit laptop I have in only starts if I run it from command line using `java -jar "C:\Name of Jar.jar"` but throws no errors whatsoever.

Furthermore though, if I use the command `javaw "C:\Name Of Jar.jar"` I get an error message saying "Could not find the main class C:\Name of Jar.jar. Program will exit."

Does anybody know why, and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Java will run the same regardless of bitness. Try `java -jar thejar.jar package.MainClass`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh ok, I didn't realise. What's the point in offering two different JVMs then? Anyway, I wasn't looking for command line solutions - I need to be able to make the JAR double clickable. Thank you anyway!

Comment: The 64-bit version uses more registers and can use much memory. The 32-bit version is required on 32-bit OSes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok thank you. But a JAR compiled using a 64 bit JDK will run on a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: Whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit it will create the same JAR which will run on either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you build it with JDK 1.7?
Maybe you haven't installed JRE7 on the pc you try to run it.
It's an odd bug I encountered several times.

Comment: Ah ha - I feel rather stupid now. I didn't realise the 32 bit laptop didn't have JRE 7 on; I didn't even realise I didn't have JRE 6 on my laptop. I've installed JRE 6 (32 bit) on my laptop and exported the executable JAR again and now it works perfectly on all my laptops now. It also seems a bit faster to me.

Comment: That's just the reaction I had, when I discovered the issue.
This bug came with Oracle as they released 1.7 ;)

Comment: :) Ah. I did think that even if an application was compiled using 1.7, as long as it only used methods available in 1.6, it should work with only 1.6. And the same for 1.6 and 1.5 etc. Am I mistaken, or is this the bug in 1.7?

Comment: This is indeed the way it used to work. Normally those new funktions are compatible in their bytecode with older versions...
I can't remember if I read this in an Oracle bugreport, but imo it should be an official bug in the runtime.(1.7 ofc)

Answer (score 1):

On your 32-bit machine right-click -> Open With on the JAR.  If a JRE is listed, you can open with it, and make it the default program to run with.

I don't think it has to do with the 32 or 64-bit OS.

Comment: You are right. I don't think the fact that it was compiled/exported on a 64-bit system made a difference. Unfortunately you're solution didn't help - my problem was because the 32 bit I was testing on didn't have JRE 7 on. I've fixed everything now but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try `javaw -jar jar_name`. I think that might do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, that made it execute fine without error, but as I said before, I wasn't really looking for a command line solution - I need to fix my executable JAR. I've got it solved now but thank you anyway.