# Compiling Java jar on windows 64 bit and executing it on RPI 32 bit

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

[Searched StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288141/jar-compiled-on-64-bit-windows-wont-run-on-32-bit)

The following code works fine when I run it as a jar file on Windows 10 64 bit machine but when I copy  the jar file over to a RPI, it consistently generates the Bad message error. I tried the suggestion to use JAVAW from the above link but the command cannot be found on the RPI.  IOW, the checksum can't be correctly calculated on the RPI.  Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
int messageBody[] = new int[(messageLen / 2) - 2];
checkSum = 0;
            for (int charPtr = 2; charPtr < messageLen; ) {
                firstChar = theMessage.charAt(charPtr++);
                secondChar = theMessage.charAt(charPtr++);
                theValue = ((firstChar >= 'A' ? (firstChar - 'A') + 10 : (firstChar - '0')) << 4)
                        | (secondChar >= 'A' ? (secondChar - 'A') + 10 : (secondChar - '0'));

                if (messagePtr < messageBody.length) {
                    checkSum += theValue;
                    messageBody[messagePtr++] = theValue;
                    continue;
                }
                // Compute checksum

                checkSum = (-checkSum & 0xff);
                if (checkSum != theValue) {
                    System.err.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Check sum on received UPB packet failed -- should be " + checkSum + " but received as " + theValue);
                    System.err.println(System.lineSeparator() +"   BAD MESSAGE[" + theMessage + "], " + theMessage.length() + " bytes");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the error message you are seeing.

Comment: PA-Feb-2016 18:45:19 Received: PU280501FF7A8600D3

Check sum on received UPB packet failed -- should be 0 but received as -551                                                                                                               The D3 (0xD3) is the actual checksum.  It is based upon adding 0x28, 0x05, 0x01,0xff, 0x7A,0x86 and 0x00 then doing a 2's complement and finally truncating the result to 8 bits

Comment: From the look of it, your error is really just programmer-imposed, as-in not an Exception being throw. Further, it looks like you will always have this "error", since you compare the checksum with a non checksum value, and they don't appear to be likely the same after running the rest of your algorithm. Further, if you are expecting D3 as your checksum, but recived -551 or 0, then obviously you have a bug in your checksum algorithm.

Comment: You should tell us where the message is comming from. Java is portable, so if the JAR file is the same and the input is the same, results should be identical. In this case the JAR is the same, so the difference should be in the input, as Grogi points out...

Comment: I've narrowed it down somewhat.  I'm reading a string as input from a serial port and it seems as though I'm getting two extraneous characters on a read causing messageLen to be larger than needed in order to correctly calculate the checksum, IOW, the routine would only need 6 hex string input to correctly calculate the checksum but it is receiving 8 because of the extraneous serial port char read.  Thus, screwing up the checksum calc.  Have to figure out why I'm getting that extra char read with RPI and not Windows 10 desktop

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to my mind is different string encoding...

Answer (score -3):

The native code in java which is written in 32/64 bit is not portable and we need to recompile in target environment.

**Reference url:**  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_native_porting

Hi Grogi & Bob S,
Thanks for the input.

Comment: Java is platform agnostic... I can compile on Linux 64bit and run it on 32bit Windows.

Comment: I've searched StackOverlow and other forums and that seems to be the general consensus which totally befuddles me.  It's all bytecode (8bits) so it should run without any problems on any platform.